# Disable native CF purge job

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

We have physical load balancer for application and it run from 3 different CF servers & each different instances. They all have a common DB in back-end. We ue Client variables stored in this DB. We are getting into deadlock on the tables (cdata & cglobal) when CF purge runs. We understand that purge is running from multiple servers and somehow run into race condition. If we have to disable purge from server B & C, while allowing it run from A, how I can disable the job. Only thing configurable I see is time after it run with default of 67 minutes and older record to delete (90 days older default)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to contact Adobe directly about this. Client variables have not been a recommended way of managing session data for quite some time.

- [Configuring and using client variables](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/developing-cfml-applications/using-persistent-data-and-locking/configuring-and-using-client-variables.html)
- [Managing the client state](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/developing-cfml-applications/using-persistent-data-and-locking/managing-the-client-state.html)

This site shows the CF Admin settings for Client Variables. You might try just unchecking the purge setting on whichever servers or instances you don't want to run the process.

- https://www.cfguide.io/coldfusion-administrator/client-variables/

[image: Client Variables Purge Settings]

[image: Client Variables Purge Interval]